# Get all (unique) matches in table and use them within SUMIF/S function as conditional

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
-> PAYMENT METHODS TABLE   
NAME SCORE
A    4
B    5
C    6

-> BOOKINGS TABLE
ID DATE   CLIENT   PAYED WITH   PRICE
1  10APR  JHON     A            500
2  10JUN  PATRICK  B            1000
3  10JUL  JHON     A            300
4  15JUL  JHON     C            500
```

I have two tables like these, basically what i need is to be able to filter on bookings table by several filters (date, client, price) and then from all the matches get the 'payment method' name and add up their respective score in 'payment methods table'. Which means i need to get an array of 'payment methods names' (from the matching bookings) and use that as filter probably within a SUMIF function.

I tried to use this:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(PAYMENT_METHODS_TABLE[NAME],INDEX(BOOKINGS_TABLE[PAYED_WITH],MATCH(1,(BOOKINGS_TABLE[CLIENT]:BOOKINGS_TABLE[CLIENT]="JOHN")*(BOOKINGS_TABLE[DATE]:BOOKINGS_TABLE[DATE]>="10/06/2020"),0)),PAYMENT_METHODS_TABLE[SCORE]))
```

Making it an array formula CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER but it doesnt work, the MATCH function returns only the first 'payment method name' but not all of them

The Formula i want to achieve (Using same criteria than above) should look like this:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(PAYMENT_METHODS_TABLE[NAME],{"B","C"},PAYMENT_METHODS_TABLE[SCORE]))
```

Comment: So you are going to use the filter to filter the data, and you want to use sumifs on the visible data to come up with the sum?

Comment: @ScottCraner, no, i need to write a formula that will filter the data and will return an array which i will use within a SUMIF formula to get what i need

Comment: how are you filtering the data.  What formula have you tried to filter the data?  Filter the data is a broad statement.

Comment: @ScottCraner i edited the question with the best approach i could come up with

Answer (score 0):

To check if the row is visible or not we use SUBTOTAL:

```
SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(BT[[#Headers],[ID]],ROW(BT[ID])-MIN(ROW(BT[ID]))+1,,1,1))
```

This iterates the rows in the table and returns `1` if visible and `0` if not.

Then we use LOOKUP:

```
 LOOKUP(BT[PAYED WITH],PMT[NAME],PMT[SCORE])
```

To return the correct value.

We then multiply it all together and wrap in a SUMPRODUCT to do the sum:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(BT[[#Headers],[ID]],ROW(BT[ID])-MIN(ROW(BT[ID]))+1,,1,1))>0)*(LOOKUP(BT[PAYED WITH],PMT[NAME],PMT[SCORE])))
```

[image]

Then you can filter the first table any way you want and the sum will change:

[image: []

Comment: Thanks, seems like i didnt explain myself well when referring to filtering the data, anyway your approach is interesting for actual filters.